# How to display an attached file (jpg) in views-view--custom.tpl.php

Tags: 7, views, theming

So I am new to Drupal but just have been tasked with theming a drupal 7 site. I am finding it hard to find the info I need to do this, I think it is because I just don't know what to google... but anyways the current task I am trying to figure out is how to take an attached image from a node and display it in a view.

I post some screen shots of the info I have, as I am pretty sure I don't know the exact drupal words to express what I am needing.

I need the image from this node:
[image]

That is selected by this view:
[image]

and the view is currently using the file views-view--spotlight.tpl.php

I really hope this makes sense, I have been googling my heart out to find out how to do this, if I am barking up the wrong tree I would gladly take advice as to which tree I should bark up.

Comment: The file should be available under fields. But you seem to be requesting it's id rather then the file. Have a look at the content type and find the field name, from there you should be able to find it in views - fields.